# Ping application in ios

Tags: ios

is there any method to follow the applications on ios devices? 
For instance , can I ping to ios devices on server side? or can I send silent push to device to get if application runs or not?
Thank you.

Comment: No you can not do that. Imagine and iOS device as a sanctified place where you can not enter without an invitation. The opposite is possible, an app "pinging" a server.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to let the app sending 'online' and 'offline' *(combined with some unique per device id to the server)* every time it gets open and closed. Then your server can store the state in some kind of database and you can read it from there if an app is currently online or offline on the client device.

Comment: I see, well is there any possible method something like "push listener" etc. ? I mean that if I send a push notification , can I listen it without login on app?

Comment: No, push automatically starts app, even in background.